# Money formatting directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, format, currency

I need a directive for filtering a field for currency, so a user just needs to type and the decimal is implied.

Needs:

1. Format decimal field as user types  -

**Start at the hundredths place as the user types. So they would type "4" and see "0.04", type "42" and see "0.42", type 298023 and see "2980.23"**

2. Field must be a number
3. Must allow negatives `-`
4. Allow 0.00 as a number input
5. Ideally would use type="number" but "type=text" is okay
6. You should be able to clear the field to be empty.

The ng-currency filter does not fulfill these requirements as is. Please see behaviour in plunkers to see what I mean.

My [First Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GZhVaNaMcewii8jN3oUn?p=preview) has `input = text' and allows negative numbers. One problem is that you cannot type a negative as the very first number. When you clear the field, it returns to '0.00' but it should completely clear.

```
   app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
 return {
            require: 'ngModel', //there must be ng-model in the html
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                if (!ctrl) return;

                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, modelValue) {
                    var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^-+0-9]/g,'');
                    var newVal = plainNumber.charAt(plainNumber.length-1);
                    var positive = plainNumber.charAt(0) != '-';
                    if(isNaN(plainNumber.charAt(plainNumber.length-1))){
                      plainNumber = plainNumber.substr(0,plainNumber.length-1)
                    }
                    //use angular internal 'number' filter
                    plainNumber = $filter('number')(plainNumber / 100, 2).replace(/,/g, '');
                    if(positive && newVal == '-'){
                      plainNumber = '-' + plainNumber;
                    }
                    else if(!positive && newVal == '+'){
                      plainNumber = plainNumber.substr(1);
                    }
                    plainNumber.replace('.', ',');

                    //update the $viewValue
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(plainNumber);
                    //reflect on the DOM element
                    ctrl.$render();
                    //return the modified value to next parser
                    return plainNumber;
                });
            }
        };

}]);
```

My [Second Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uc9djyvy0SrIG9RF7Fbh?p=preview) has `input = text` and allows for negative input. Like the first plunker, it won't allow a negative as the first character, only after numbers are typed. The second is that it starts at the tenths place instead of the hundredths. (if you type '3' you should see '0.03' but here it shows '0.3')

```
app.directive('inputRestrictor', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            var pattern = /[^.0-9+-]/g;

            function fromUser(text) {
                if (!text)
                return text;

                var rep = /[+]/g;
                var rem = /[-]/g;
                rep.exec(text);
                rem.exec(text);

                var indexp = rep.lastIndex;
                var indexm = rem.lastIndex;
                text = text.replace(/[+.-]/g, '');
                if (indexp > 0 || indexm > 0) {
                    if (indexp > indexm) text = "+" + text; // plus sign?
                    else text = "-" + text;
                }

                var transformedInput = text.replace(pattern, '');
                transformedInput = transformedInput.replace(/([0-9]{1,2}$)/, ".$1")
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                ngModelCtrl.$render();
                return transformedInput;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I reconcile these solutions or tailor one to meet the requirements? I want to avoid extra libraries or add-ons. I have been told that the best approach would be to study the source for the currency filter, and recreate that filter with the additional requirements.I would love to do this, but I really don't have the skills for it right now. These two directives are what I have.

Comment: angular has a currency filter built in: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 that filter is nice but it does not meet the requirements of adding a decimal point as a user types. This is what the directive is for. To see what I mean, type in the plunker field and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, [ng-currency](https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency) is helpful.

Comment: @jenryb did you check new answer?

Comment: Angular's built in currency filter DOES add decimal points as the user types, and is even configurable as to how many places you want to round to: `{{amount | currency:"USD$":4}}` will show 4 places after the decimal.

Comment: @adamdport It adds .00 to the end, but I want the typing to start in the hundreds place.  If you compare the angular docs solution to my plunker do you see what I mean?

Comment: I do now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jenryb Checkout updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## .:: Updated Answer - July 14 ::.

---

Check this simple directive:

```
app.directive('price', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            attrs.$set('ngTrim', "false");

            var formatter = function(str, isNum) {
                str = String( Number(str || 0) / (isNum?1:100) );
                str = (str=='0'?'0.0':str).split('.');
                str[1] = str[1] || '0';
                return str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, '$1,') + '.' + (str[1].length==1?str[1]+'0':str[1]);
            }
            var updateView = function(val) {
                scope.$applyAsync(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(val || '');
                    ngModel.$render();
                });
            }
            var parseNumber = function(val) {
                var modelString = formatter(ngModel.$modelValue, true);
                var sign = {
                    pos: /[+]/.test(val),
                    neg: /[-]/.test(val)
                }
                sign.has = sign.pos || sign.neg;
                sign.both = sign.pos && sign.neg;

                if (!val || sign.has && val.length==1 || ngModel.$modelValue && Number(val)===0) {
                    var newVal = (!val || ngModel.$modelValue && Number()===0?'':val);
                    if (ngModel.$modelValue !== newVal)
                        updateView(newVal);

                    return '';
                }
                else {
                    var valString = String(val || '');
                    var newSign = (sign.both && ngModel.$modelValue>=0 || !sign.both && sign.neg?'-':'');
                    var newVal = valString.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    var viewVal = newSign + formatter(angular.copy(newVal));

                    if (modelString !== valString)
                        updateView(viewVal);

                    return (Number(newSign + newVal) / 100) || 0;
                }
            }
            var formatNumber = function(val) {
                if (val) {
                    var str = String(val).split('.');
                    str[1] = str[1] || '0';
                    val = str[0] + '.' + (str[1].length==1?str[1]+'0':str[1]);
                }
                return parseNumber(val);
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(parseNumber);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(formatNumber);
        }
    };
}]);
```

And use it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="number" price >
```

**See it live in this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4MW49Rr3XDFjMW5gamL?p=preview) (July 14)**

Comment: Close, but this does not add a decimal after two digits, which should reflect in the view as well as the model.

Comment: @jenryb You mean, you want to force 2 digit after decimal point?

Comment: Yes. See behaviour of either of the plunkers to see what I mean

Comment: @jenryb Ok, no problem

Comment: This one is so close. But you still cannot put in a "-" negative sign as the first character (unless the number is already there) An example of this is my second plunker, which allowed the switch between negative and positive. If you can get it working with this I can accept this answer.

Comment: Also your plunker does not allow zeros which is a problem too.

Comment: If you fix it I will accept your answer and give you the bounty

Comment: Still is not quite working. If you delete the number, you cannot change it to a negative again. Also you cannot toggle between - and + (see first plunker) it is still close

Comment: @jenryb you mean whenever you hit - or + the whole number sign change?

Comment: Yes. I noticed that in yours if you type a number, then delete it so it goes back to 0.00, now you are not able to put in a - or + . Also ideally it will make an entire sign change to toggle between. I added a check for this in the first plunker when I edited the question, so it works

Comment: @jenryb what if its '0.01' and user hit backspace? and when its '0.00' and user hit '-' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117352/discussion-between-jenryb-and-mete-30).

Comment: Mind putting your code onto bower/npm? I could help

Comment: Hi @MeTe-30 coule you help me converting this into angular 8 code. Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

i think this can full fill your requirement

```
https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number
```

you can restrict the input that allows only numbers with decimals by default angular input validations or by using char code.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular Numeric**

Angular Numeric is a sophisticated directive that implements a complete numeric input field.

Very simple to use - yet powerful.

```
<input numeric min="-20" max="100" decimals="3" />
```

> There are checks on min and max values. When the value falls below the
>   minumum the value is set to the minumum value. When the value exceeds
>   the maxiumum, the value is set to the maximum.
>
> Formatting is done on the blur event; thousand separator and decimal
>   are based on the current Angular locale.
>
> The number of decimals can be set.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-numeric-directive

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't want to format on blur, instead it should be while the user types.