# Angular filter for currency to allow typing negative numbers

Tags: angularjs, filter, format, currency, angular-directive

I have a directive that filters currency by adding a decimal point as the user types.

My problem is that it will not allow negatives. It would be nice to allow a user to type a '-' sign and have it always appear at the beginning of the number, or type a '+' and have it disappear.

Needs:

1. Format decimal field as user types
2. Field must be a number
3. Must allow negatives `-`
4. Allow 0.00 as a number input

[Check out my  Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qlZrc7dnZEUWzoNGyaF6?p=preview) . It has `input = number` but does not allow negative numbers:

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel', //there must be ng-model in the html
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, modelValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^-+0-9]/g,'');

                // use angular internal 'number' filter
                plainNumber = $filter('number')(plainNumber / 100, 2).replace(/,/g, '');

                // update the $viewValue
                ctrl.$setViewValue(plainNumber);

                // reflect on the DOM element
                ctrl.$render();

                // return the modified value to next parser
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [built in currency filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)? *edit: I see your other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062482/money-formatting-directive-in-angular). The demo on angular's currency filter DOES add the 0s to the input. I don't understand why it's insufficient for you.

Comment: and to echo what @adamdport stated, how exactly is this question different from the first question you asked?  the built in currency filter does indeed satisfy ***all*** of the requirements that you have asked about from both questions, unless you aren't using it correctly.

Comment: in fact, looking at your post history, you have asked the same question **4!** times.  Asking more than once isn't going to make it more likely to get an answer, and in fact it makes it harder for others who might have a similar issue.

Comment: @jenryb Your code was good, it just needed a small modification to work correctly. Check answer for details.

Comment: @Claies sorry for the duplicates. I think I was asking too much in the first so I broke it down here. I think I should have been more clear about why the ng-currency filter wasn't working. It does NOT fulfill my requirements, as adamdport found once trying the plunkers I've supplied. There is a chance I'm not using it to its full potential, in that case please supply an answer with an example.

Comment: you mention in one comment on one post that you want to start at the hundredths place with the filter.  In none of your questions where you list requirements do you list that.  If that is an additional requirement, you should update the single question that is still open and add the additional requirement.  that being said, your best approach would be to study the source for the currency filter, and recreate that filter with the additional requirements. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L7

Comment: @Claies, gotcha. Edited the original to be more clear. Also added a bounty to it if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you want it to do:

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {


});

 app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
 return {
            require: 'ngModel', //there must be ng-model in the html
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                if (!ctrl) return;

                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, modelValue) {
                    var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^-+0-9]/g,'');
                    var newVal = plainNumber.charAt(plainNumber.length-1);
                    var positive = plainNumber.charAt(0) != '-';
                    if(isNaN(plainNumber.charAt(plainNumber.length-1))){
                      plainNumber = plainNumber.substr(0,plainNumber.length-1)
                    }
                    //use angular internal 'number' filter
                    plainNumber = $filter('number')(plainNumber / 100, 2).replace(/,/g, '');
                    if(positive && newVal == '-'){
                      plainNumber = '-' + plainNumber;
                    }
                    else if(!positive && newVal == '+'){
                      plainNumber = plainNumber.substr(1);
                    }
                    plainNumber.replace('.', ',');
                    //update the $viewValue
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(plainNumber);
                    //reflect on the DOM element
                    ctrl.$render();
                    //return the modified value to next parser
                    return plainNumber;
                });
            }
        };

}]);
```

Just remove the type="number" from:

```
<input ng-model="amount" format="number" />
```

Comment: One more thing, do you know how I could change the period to a comma? Also the directive won't let me clear the field, do you know why?

Comment: Check edit for comma and for clearing, you cannot because the number filter causes it to format to a decimal number all the time

Comment: Why you remove best answer?

Comment: Sorry, mistake. I put it back. Using your answer plnkr.co/edit/zUT4cyqtbs3Xn7J7oapj?p=preview I still cannot put in a negative as the first entry. Also the change for the comma is not working.